# How to convert a text file in a set line range to json format by Python

Tags: python, json, file

I consider to use a for loop to read a file, but I only want to read specific block .Then convert into json format.

Example:

```
# Summary Report #######################
              System time | 2020-02-27 15:35:32 UTC (local TZ: UTC +0000)
# Instances ##################################################
  Port  Data Directory             Nice OOM Socket
  ===== ========================== ==== === ======
                                   0    0   
# Configuration File #########################################
              Config File | /etc/srv.cnf
[server]
server_id            = 1
port                                = 3016
tmpdir                              = /tmp
[client]
port                                = 3016
# management library ##################################
# The End ####################################################
```

[txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA2LK.png)

capture specific block:

```
[server]
server_id            = 1
port                                = 3016
tmpdir                              = /tmp

[client]
port                                = 3016
```

[block content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTkPF.png)

The resulting json is:

```
{
   "server": {
          "server_id":"1",
          "port":"3016",
          "tmpdir":"/tmp"

   },
   "client": {
          "port": "3016"
   }
}
```

[resulting json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1efu.png)

Is there any built-in feature to achieve this?

I tried to use the following to parse text file. But it did not work.

```
import json

filename = 'conf.txt'

commands = {}
with open(filename) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        command, description = line.strip().split('=', 1)
        commands[command.rstrip()] = description.strip()

print(json.dumps(commands, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: wat you've tried so far?

Comment: What is the output you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, never post screenshots, use the editor to type out the text.

You have to edit based on your requirements, it makes some assumptions based on your sample.

sample_input.txt

```
## SASADA
# RANDOM
XXXX
[server]
server_id = 1
port = 8000
[client]
port = 8001
```

code.py

```
all_lines = open('sample_input.txt', 'r').readlines() # reads all the lines from the text file

# skip lines, look for patterns here []
final_dict = {}

server = 0 # not yet found server
for line in all_lines:
   if '[server]' in line:
       final_dict['server'] = {}
       server = 1
   if '[client]' in line:
       final_dict['client'] = {}
       server = 2
   if server == 1:
       try:
          clean_line = line.strip() # get rid of empty space
          k = clean_line.split('=')[0] # get the key
          v = clean_line.split('=')[1]
          final_dict['server'][k] = v
       except:
          passs

   if server == 2:
       # add try except too
       clean_line = line.strip() # get rid of empty space
       k = clean_line.split('=')[0] # get the key
       v = clean_line.split('=')[1]
       final_dict['client'][k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all lines from a file_handle in the following way.

```
def read_lines(file_path, from_index, to_index):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file_handle:
        return file_handle.readlines()[from_index:to_index]
```

Next part is processing the selected lines to json